# Implementing Matrix class with array of pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, multidimensional-array

I made two custom classes: a Vector class(algebraic one, not std::vector), and a Matrix class.
I easily implemented Vector class as a array of doubles, i.e i store entries like this:

```
double *tab = nullptr;
//in constructors
//tab = new double[size]{};
```

I have a problem with Matrix class though. It is supposed to be a array of pointers to Vectors, i.e:

```
Vector** tab = nullptr;
//dimensions
int m, n;
```

What if i simply do not implement it this way, and just do a array of Vectors rather than pointers?

```
Vector* tab = nullptr 
//...
//destructor looks like this  
Matrix::~Matrix(){
    delete[] tab;
    m = n = 0;
}
```

The latter seems to be easier in implementation, there is no need to call destructor for every Vector in tab. Am I missing some kind of memory leak? If not why would i ever use the first implementation.

Comment: Try using std:array, or std::vector if the size has to be dynamic.

Comment: It does not need to be dynamic, i want it to be constant size. I know i could use built-in std objects, but the point is I want to practice, and i am just having trouble understanding why should i prefer array of pointers to pointers of an object, instead of simply array of pointers to object.

Comment: And `std::array` is exactly that: *This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array T[N] as its only non-static data member.* Except it removed the bothersome decaying to pointer and adds bounds checking in the `at` method, iterators and a bunch of other useful stuff. Get rid of the pointers completely.

Answer (score 0):

> If not why would i ever use the first implementation.

Probably the primary reason that you might want to use an array of arrays is that it allows you to to turn the row-column notation of a matrix, i.e. `m[1][0]` into access to the correct offset without having to do any math.  If you matrix is a single dimensional array and someone asks for a given row and column you have to compute the 1D offset from the 2D information you've been given.

Of course there are ways around this.  For instance, you could declare your matrix like this:

```cpp
class Matrix {
public:
  double * _values;
  double ** _rows;

  Matrix() {
    _values = new double[16];
    _rows = new double*[4];
    auto start = _values;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      _rows[i] = start;
      start += 4;
    }
  }

  ~Matrix() {
    delete[] _rows;
    delete[] _values;
  }
}
```

Now, you've allocated one block of doubles and one block of `double*` for your row offsets.  If you want to get a given row `r` and column `c` you can access it as `_rows[r][c]` without doing any computation.

Alternatively, you could also construct your `Matrix` type out of a collection of `Vectors` rather than the internal value type directly.

Comment: The thing is, class Vector is implemented as an array of doubles. I also overloaded [] operator. The same goes for Matrix class, it is an dynamic array of my Vector class objects, with [] overloaded, and For example if A is a 5x3 Matrix -> `Matrix A(3,5)` then it does behave like 2d array (i can access elements this way `A[0][2]` etc.) I just do not see why i would want to do array of pointers to pointers of an object, instead of simply array of pointers to object